# DataTables select & responsive, child rows. How to collapse child rows?

Tags: jquery, datatables

If I use the `DataTable`'s both `responsive` and `select` extension I get a confusing behavior:

1. Click a row and it becomes selected and expanded to show child rows.
   OK.
2. Click another row and so this one becomes selected and expanded.
   Still OK.
3. Click first row again and it become selected but collapsed. NOT OK.

How can I make rows behave similar to jQuery UI Accordion? Meaning, collapse all unselected row's children after I make a new selection?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pm2gk9we/12/

Comment: can you provide an example, jsFiddle, jsBin, CodePen, ...

Comment: Here you go, see edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with - I hide child rows after row click:

```
$("tr").unbind("click").click(function () {
 $("#table").DataTable().rows().every(function () {
   this.child((this.data())).hide();          
 });
});
```

It works fine when I initialize `responsive` like this (to hide the icon on the left and expand row on every cell:

```
new $.fn.dataTable.Responsive(table, {
                        details: {
                            type: 'column',
                            target: 'tr'
                        }
                    });
```

Solution fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pm2gk9we/13/